# React Native build error duplicate key on values.xml between different dependencies

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm already search several information related to this issue. When I use `com.midtrans:uikit:1.21.2` and `:react-native-camera` then run the build script, this error occurred.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
  Output:  /rootProject/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:492: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/aspectRatio' with config ''.
  /rootProject/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:492: error: resource previously defined here.

  Command: /userRoot/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx.jar/26099ef957fce779fbc384e01d71f8d6/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx/aapt2 compile --legacy \
          -o \
          /rootProject/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug \
          /rootProject/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx Daemon #0
  Output:  /userRoot/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/cardview-v7-26.1.0.aar/f44a4b5427df6e671eadd76860228e04/res/values/values.xml:7:5-685: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/aspectRatio' with config ''.

  /userRoot/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/cardview-v7-26.1.0.aar/f44a4b5427df6e671eadd76860228e04/res/values/values.xml:7:5-685: AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.

  Command: /userRoot/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx.jar/26099ef957fce779fbc384e01d71f8d6/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx/aapt2 compile --legacy \
          -o \
          /rootProject/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug \
          /rootProject/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx Daemon #0
```

This error is refers to this line on `rootProject/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml`
[image]

Then i found that if there are multiple key with the same value.

1. `react-native-camera` [resources](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/blob/57bc327d847ccb7ea90ded51a5a82168388b1349/android/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml#L29) on `android/src/main/res/value/attrs.xml` with key `<attr format="string" name="aspectRatio"/>`
2. `com.midtrans:uikit` [resources](https://github.com/veritrans/veritrans-android/blob/241678bec4ae85473f7b9036d3827e3256bccdef/uikit/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml#L74) on `uikit/src/main/res/value/attrs.xml` with key `<attr format="float" name="aspectRatio"/>`

I need help to fix this error, or any information to fix/avoid this situation.
There are some thread that I checked.

1. [React Native : Error: Duplicate resources - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53239705/react-native-error-duplicate-resources-android)
2. [Unable to build android (because of duplicate dependecies ?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53041713/unable-to-build-android-because-of-duplicate-dependecies)
3. [React Native Error: Duplicate resources, assets coming in some screens and not coming in others in android release APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52668524/react-native-error-duplicate-resources-assets-coming-in-some-screens-and-not-c)

Any help would be thanks.

Comment: Try this command rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache verify && npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache..

It works for me. Before running it, shut the Android Studio, if open.

Comment: @AadityaPaliwal I tried it, but `no matches found: /var/folders/jr/k4qv5jt10nb462n4f_vc76p80000gn/T//react-*` occured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few solution you might interested to:

1. Fork the react-native-camera in GitHub to yours and modify the styles.xml and attrs.xml and add it to your react native project.
2. Use the other's forked project from com.midtrans in [here](https://github.com/veritrans/veritrans-android/pull/591). Veritrans has clearly stated that they won't support react-native project and might not merge this pull request.

I will recommend the solution no 1. I have forked and modify the resource value and some modification on others to follow my requirement needs. Feel free to take a look: [here](https://github.com/nowarzz/react-native-camera)